# how to move column to another existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The column is a decimal with default value 0 and has just been added in the target table. In the target table the row (with that id) might not exist yet. So sometimes the value must be updated and sometimes a new row with existing id and value must be inserted.

What I got so far:

```
insert into nieuw (p_id, b)
select p_id, a
from oud
update nieuw
set nieuw.b = oud.a
from oud o
inner join nieuw n
on o.p_id = n.p_id;
```

I've tried several iterations and always get errors like 'Invalid column name'.

Comment: Have a look at the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: [I'd actually not recommend jumping on `MERGE` out of the gates](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: As far as I know, your `INSERT`/`SELECT`/`UPDATE` syntax isn't supported.  You can use an `UPDATE` from an `INNER JOIN` to handle the rows that already exist. You'll need a separate `INSERT` statement to handle the unmatched rows. Refer to Dr Bertrand's blog for information about `WHERE NOT EXISTS` vs. checking for NULLs on JOINs and other reasons not to do anything I might suggest. If this is more than a one-time offline event then you'll need to consider wrapping it in a transaction.

Comment: This only has to happen once so I ended up using C# code with NHibernate for this.

Should I delete this question? Or can it maybe be answered for other languagues or maybe if the SQL-server merge bugs get fixed?